# Accessing environment variables set in R session from shell

Tags: r

In my R session, I'm setting some environment variables using

```
Sys.setenv(BLAH="blah")
```

When I switch to the terminal (Ctrl-Z) and then try to access the environment variable, I see that it is not set.

```
echo $BLAH
```

The question is, where is the environment variable that I set from R, and if I want another process to see it, how can I get access to it?

Answer (score 7, accepted):

The environmental variable dies with the process.

Each process has its own set of environmental variables, inherited from the parent process. When you create the environmental variable `BLAH`, you create it in the environment of the R process you're running, but not in the environment of the parent process.

If you want another process to access this environmental variable, you'll need to start the process from within R. Then the child process will inherit `BLAH`. This documentation for `Sys.setenv` mentions this:

> Sys.setenv sets environment variables (*for other processes called from within R* or future calls to Sys.getenv from this R process).

For example:

```
Sys.setenv(BLAH="blah")
system("echo $BLAH")
# blah
```

Comment: On Windows you need to use `%variableName%` rather than `$variableName`.  And `system` gave me an error, so I had to use `shell("echo %BLAH%")`.

Comment: Interesting. `?system` mentions that on Windows, `system` runs the command directly, while `shell` runs it via a shell. Didn't know that.

Comment: The help page for `system` says to now use `system2`